# HoloEveryWhere still remains as a puzzle

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I have downloaded holoeverywhere from github,imported to eclipse ,added AcrionBarSherlock library problem with maven dependencies,

then followed the instructions from stack overflow downloaded latest version from github,but if i add ABS in res/layout/attr.xml error as some tags already defined,but if i remove ABS library some of the tag elements remains unknown for the library ,,please give the working solution,if posible so me some tutorials or examples that will guide step by step in importing  holoeverywhere library into workspace

Comment: I can't help as I didn't worked with the HoleEveryWhere library. You should try a fresh install with all the libraries downloaded again following the tutorial. If you still don't manage to do it you should post an issue on the github page of the project with all the details, the creators should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the working solution for Holoeverywhere library in the following link

https://github.com/GrioSF/HoloEverywhere