# NoClassDefFound Exception for SearchView in devices below 3.0 but works above 3.0

Tags: android

NoClassDefFound Exception for SearchView in devices below 3.0 but works above 3.0,

I used the following library for downporting to devices below 3.0,,

https://github.com/inazaruk/abs-search-view

but exception occurs

Following is my search View class

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.searchview.example.activity;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.searchview.example.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;


/**
 * Shows a list that can be filtered in-place with a SearchView in non-iconified mode.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends SherlockActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchViewFilterMode";

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.cheese_hunt_hint));
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
class Cheeses {

    public static final String[] sCheeseStrings = {
            "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale",
            "Aisy Cendre", "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Alverca", "Ambert", "American Cheese",
            "Ami du Chambertin", "Anejo Enchilado", "Anneau du Vic-Bilh", "Anthoriro", "Appenzell",
            "Aragon", "Ardi Gasna", "Ardrahan", "Armenian String", "Aromes au Gene de Marc",
            "Asadero", "Asiago", "Aubisque Pyrenees", "Autun", "Avaxtskyr", "Baby Swiss",
            "Babybel", "Baguette Laonnaise", "Bakers", "Baladi", "Balaton", "Bandal", "Banon",
            "Barry's Bay Cheddar", "Basing", "Basket Cheese", "Bath Cheese", "Bavarian Bergkase",
            "Baylough", "Beaufort", "Beauvoorde", "Beenleigh Blue", "Beer Cheese", "Bel Paese",
            "Bergader", "Bergere Bleue", "Berkswell", "Beyaz Peynir", "Bierkase", "Bishop Kennedy",
            "Blarney", "Bleu d'Auvergne", "Bleu de Gex", "Bleu de Laqueuille",
            "Bleu de Septmoncel", "Bleu Des Causses", "Blue", "Blue Castello", "Blue Rathgore",
            "Blue Vein (Australian)", "Blue Vein Cheeses", "Bocconcini", "Bocconcini (Australian)",
            "Boeren Leidenkaas", "Bonchester", "Bosworth", "Bougon", "Boule Du Roves",
            "Boulette d'Avesnes", "Boursault", "Boursin", "Bouyssou", "Bra", "Braudostur",
            "Breakfast Cheese", "Brebis du Lavort", "Brebis du Lochois", "Brebis du Puyfaucon",
            "Bresse Bleu", "Brick", "Brie", "Brie de Meaux", "Brie de Melun", "Brillat-Savarin",
            "Brin", "Brin d' Amour", "Brin d'Amour", "Brinza (Burduf Brinza)",
            "Briquette de Brebis", "Briquette du Forez", "Broccio", "Broccio Demi-Affine",
            "Brousse du Rove", "Bruder Basil", "Brusselae Kaas (Fromage de Bruxelles)", "Bryndza",
            "Buchette d'Anjou", "Buffalo", "Burgos", "Butte", "Butterkase", "Button (Innes)",
            "Buxton Blue", "Cabecou", "Caboc", "Cabrales", "Cachaille", "Caciocavallo", "Caciotta",
            "Caerphilly", "Cairnsmore", "Calenzana", "Cambazola", "Camembert de Normandie",
            "Canadian Cheddar", "Canestrato", "Cantal", "Caprice des Dieux", "Capricorn Goat",
            "Capriole Banon", "Carre de l'Est", "Casciotta di Urbino", "Cashel Blue", "Castellano",
            "Castelleno", "Castelmagno", "Castelo Branco", "Castigliano", "Cathelain",
            "Celtic Promise", "Cendre d'Olivet", "Cerney", "Chabichou", "Chabichou du Poitou",
            "Chabis de Gatine", "Chaource", "Charolais", "Chaumes", "Cheddar",
            "Cheddar Clothbound", "Cheshire", "Chevres", "Chevrotin des Aravis", "Chontaleno",
            "Civray", "Coeur de Camembert au Calvados", "Coeur de Chevre", "Colby", "Cold Pack",
            "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
            "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
            "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
            "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
            "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
            "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
            "Cypress Grove Chevre", "Danablu (Danish Blue)", "Danbo", "Danish Fontina",
            "Daralagjazsky", "Dauphin", "Delice des Fiouves", "Denhany Dorset Drum", "Derby",
            "Dessertnyj Belyj", "Devon Blue", "Devon Garland", "Dolcelatte", "Doolin",
            "Doppelrhamstufel", "Dorset Blue Vinney", "Double Gloucester", "Double Worcester",
            "Dreux a la Feuille", "Dry Jack", "Duddleswell", "Dunbarra", "Dunlop", "Dunsyre Blue",
            "Duroblando", "Durrus", "Dutch Mimolette (Commissiekaas)", "Edam", "Edelpilz",
            "Emental Grand Cru", "Emlett", "Emmental", "Epoisses de Bourgogne", "Esbareich",
            "Esrom", "Etorki", "Evansdale Farmhouse Brie", "Evora De L'Alentejo", "Exmoor Blue",
            "Explorateur", "Feta", "Feta (Australian)", "Figue", "Filetta", "Fin-de-Siecle",
            "Finlandia Swiss", "Finn", "Fiore Sardo", "Fleur du Maquis", "Flor de Guia",
            "Flower Marie", "Folded", "Folded cheese with mint", "Fondant de Brebis",
            "Fontainebleau", "Fontal", "Fontina Val d'Aosta", "Formaggio di capra", "Fougerus",
            "Four Herb Gouda", "Fourme d' Ambert", "Fourme de Haute Loire", "Fourme de Montbrison",
            "Fresh Jack", "Fresh Mozzarella", "Fresh Ricotta", "Fresh Truffles", "Fribourgeois",
            "Friesekaas", "Friesian", "Friesla", "Frinault", "Fromage a Raclette", "Fromage Corse",
            "Fromage de Montagne de Savoie", "Fromage Frais", "Fruit Cream Cheese",
            "Frying Cheese", "Fynbo", "Gabriel", "Galette du Paludier", "Galette Lyonnaise",
            "Galloway Goat's Milk Gems", "Gammelost", "Gaperon a l'Ail", "Garrotxa", "Gastanberra",
            "Geitost", "Gippsland Blue", "Gjetost", "Gloucester", "Golden Cross", "Gorgonzola",
            "Gornyaltajski", "Gospel Green", "Gouda", "Goutu", "Gowrie", "Grabetto", "Graddost",
            "Grafton Village Cheddar", "Grana", "Grana Padano", "Grand Vatel",
            "Grataron d' Areches", "Gratte-Paille", "Graviera", "Greuilh", "Greve",
            "Gris de Lille", "Gruyere", "Gubbeen", "Guerbigny", "Halloumi",
            "Halloumy (Australian)", "Haloumi-Style Cheese", "Harbourne Blue", "Havarti",
            "Heidi Gruyere", "Hereford Hop", "Herrgardsost", "Herriot Farmhouse", "Herve",
            "Hipi Iti", "Hubbardston Blue Cow", "Hushallsost", "Iberico", "Idaho Goatster",
            "Idiazabal", "Il Boschetto al Tartufo", "Ile d'Yeu", "Isle of Mull", "Jarlsberg",
            "Jermi Tortes", "Jibneh Arabieh", "Jindi Brie", "Jubilee Blue", "Juustoleipa",
            "Kadchgall", "Kaseri", "Kashta", "Kefalotyri", "Kenafa", "Kernhem", "Kervella Affine",
            "Kikorangi", "King Island Cape Wickham Brie", "King River Gold", "Klosterkaese",
            "Knockalara", "Kugelkase", "L'Aveyronnais", "L'Ecir de l'Aubrac", "La Taupiniere",
            "La Vache Qui Rit", "Laguiole", "Lairobell", "Lajta", "Lanark Blue", "Lancashire",
            "Langres", "Lappi", "Laruns", "Lavistown", "Le Brin", "Le Fium Orbo", "Le Lacandou",
            "Le Roule", "Leafield", "Lebbene", "Leerdammer", "Leicester", "Leyden", "Limburger",
            "Lincolnshire Poacher", "Lingot Saint Bousquet d'Orb", "Liptauer", "Little Rydings",  
            "Livarot", "Llanboidy", "Llanglofan Farmhouse", "Loch Arthur Farmhouse",
            "Loddiswell Avondale", "Longhorn", "Lou Palou", "Lou Pevre", "Lyonnais", "Maasdam",
            "Macconais", "Mahoe Aged Gouda", "Mahon", "Malvern", "Mamirolle", "Manchego",
            "Manouri", "Manur", "Marble Cheddar", "Marbled Cheeses", "Maredsous", "Margotin",
            "Maribo", "Maroilles", "Mascares", "Mascarpone", "Mascarpone (Australian)",
            "Mascarpone Torta", "Matocq", "Maytag Blue", "Meira", "Menallack Farmhouse",
            "Menonita", "Meredith Blue", "Mesost", "Metton (Cancoillotte)", "Meyer Vintage Gouda",
            "Mihalic Peynir", "Milleens", "Mimolette", "Mine-Gabhar", "Mini Baby Bells", "Mixte",
            "Molbo", "Monastery Cheeses", "Mondseer", "Mont D'or Lyonnais", "Montasio",
            "Monterey Jack", "Monterey Jack Dry", "Morbier", "Morbier Cru de Montagne",
            "Mothais a la Feuille", "Mozzarella", "Mozzarella (Australian)",
            "Mozzarella di Bufala", "Mozzarella Fresh, in water", "Mozzarella Rolls", "Munster",
            "Murol", "Mycella", "Myzithra", "Naboulsi", "Nantais", "Neufchatel",
            "Neufchatel (Australian)", "Niolo", "Nokkelost", "Northumberland", "Oaxaca",
            "Olde York", "Olivet au Foin", "Olivet Bleu", "Olivet Cendre",
            "Orkney Extra Mature Cheddar", "Orla", "Oschtjepka", "Ossau Fermier", "Ossau-Iraty",
            "Oszczypek", "Oxford Blue", "P'tit Berrichon", "Palet de Babligny", "Paneer", "Panela",
            "Pannerone", "Pant ys Gawn", "Parmesan (Parmigiano)", "Parmigiano Reggiano",
            "Pas de l'Escalette", "Passendale", "Pasteurized Processed", "Pate de Fromage",
            "Patefine Fort", "Pave d'Affinois", "Pave d'Auge", "Pave de Chirac", "Pave du Berry",
            "Pecorino", "Pecorino in Walnut Leaves", "Pecorino Romano", "Peekskill Pyramid",
            "Pelardon des Cevennes", "Pelardon des Corbieres", "Penamellera", "Penbryn",
            "Pencarreg", "Perail de Brebis", "Petit Morin", "Petit Pardou", "Petit-Suisse",
            "Picodon de Chevre", "Picos de Europa", "Piora", "Pithtviers au Foin",
            "Plateau de Herve", "Plymouth Cheese", "Podhalanski", "Poivre d'Ane", "Polkolbin",
            "Pont l'Eveque", "Port Nicholson", "Port-Salut", "Postel", "Pouligny-Saint-Pierre",
            "Pourly", "Prastost", "Pressato", "Prince-Jean", "Processed Cheddar", "Provolone",
            "Provolone (Australian)", "Pyengana Cheddar", "Pyramide", "Quark",
            "Quark (Australian)", "Quartirolo Lombardo", "Quatre-Vents", "Quercy Petit",
            "Queso Blanco", "Queso Blanco con Frutas --Pina y Mango", "Queso de Murcia",
            "Queso del Montsec", "Queso del Tietar", "Queso Fresco", "Queso Fresco (Adobera)",
            "Queso Iberico", "Queso Jalapeno", "Queso Majorero", "Queso Media Luna",
            "Queso Para Frier", "Queso Quesadilla", "Rabacal", "Raclette", "Ragusano", "Raschera",
            "Reblochon", "Red Leicester", "Regal de la Dombes", "Reggianito", "Remedou",
            "Requeson", "Richelieu", "Ricotta", "Ricotta (Australian)", "Ricotta Salata", "Ridder",
            "Rigotte", "Rocamadour", "Rollot", "Romano", "Romans Part Dieu", "Roncal", "Roquefort",
            "Roule", "Rouleau De Beaulieu", "Royalp Tilsit", "Rubens", "Rustinu", "Saaland Pfarr",
            "Saanenkaese", "Saga", "Sage Derby", "Sainte Maure", "Saint-Marcellin",
            "Saint-Nectaire", "Saint-Paulin", "Salers", "Samso", "San Simon", "Sancerre",
            "Sap Sago", "Sardo", "Sardo Egyptian", "Sbrinz", "Scamorza", "Schabzieger", "Schloss",
            "Selles sur Cher", "Selva", "Serat", "Seriously Strong Cheddar", "Serra da Estrela",
            "Sharpam", "Shelburne Cheddar", "Shropshire Blue", "Siraz", "Sirene", "Smoked Gouda",
            "Somerset Brie", "Sonoma Jack", "Sottocenare al Tartufo", "Soumaintrain",
            "Sourire Lozerien", "Spenwood", "Sraffordshire Organic", "St. Agur Blue Cheese",
            "Stilton", "Stinking Bishop", "String", "Sussex Slipcote", "Sveciaost", "Swaledale",
            "Sweet Style Swiss", "Swiss", "Syrian (Armenian String)", "Tala", "Taleggio", "Tamie",
            "Tasmania Highland Chevre Log", "Taupiniere", "Teifi", "Telemea", "Testouri",
            "Tete de Moine", "Tetilla", "Texas Goat Cheese", "Tibet", "Tillamook Cheddar",
            "Tilsit", "Timboon Brie", "Toma", "Tomme Brulee", "Tomme d'Abondance",
            "Tomme de Chevre", "Tomme de Romans", "Tomme de Savoie", "Tomme des Chouans", "Tommes",
            "Torta del Casar", "Toscanello", "Touree de L'Aubier", "Tourmalet",
            "Trappe (Veritable)", "Trois Cornes De Vendee", "Tronchon", "Trou du Cru", "Truffe",
            "Tupi", "Turunmaa", "Tymsboro", "Tyn Grug", "Tyning", "Ubriaco", "Ulloa",
            "Vacherin-Fribourgeois", "Valencay", "Vasterbottenost", "Venaco", "Vendomois",
            "Vieux Corse", "Vignotte", "Vulscombe", "Waimata Farmhouse Blue",
            "Washed Rind Cheese (Australian)", "Waterloo", "Weichkaese", "Wellington",
            "Wensleydale", "White Stilton", "Whitestone Farmhouse", "Wigmore", "Woodside Cabecou",
            "Xanadu", "Xynotyro", "Yarg Cornish", "Yarra Valley Pyramid", "Yorkshire Blue",
            "Zamorano", "Zanetti Grana Padano", "Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano"
    };

}
```

Help me solving the NoClassDefFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Help me solving the NoClassDefFoundException
```

Don't import the native `SearchView`(which was introduced in `Honeycomb`) with:

```
import android.widget.SearchView;
```

import the `SearchView` from the library:

```
 com.actionbarsherlock.widget.searchview.SearchView;
```

Also have a look at `ActionBarSherlock` from Jake Wharton or the version from the compatibility package(more features and more support, the project you're using hasn't been updated in over a year).

Comment: after importing it gives following error  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @GowthamRayar Well, import that listener too: `com.actionbarsherlock.widget.searchview.OnQueryTextListener` from the library. Your imports should come from the library.

Comment: Previous exception solved but new runTimeException occured saying that in layout file for <SearchView/> it shows following error   View requires API level 11 (current min is 7): <SearchView>

Comment: @GowthamRayar In the xml layout you don't just use `<SearchView .../>`, because this will again refer to the native `SearchView`, you use the one from the library: `<com.actionbarsherlock.widget.searchview.SearchView .../>`

Comment: Thank you sir it worked....Sir one more question...I know terminologies in android just cut copy paste...How to go in depth ,,,even not able to identify simple mistakes ,,any books ,,materials --guide me,,,,,once again Hats off to u sir

Comment: @GowthamRayar I don't know what to recommend, this things you'll get to know with time. You can always look at the guides on the developer site and at the sample projects, they always have very useful information.

Comment: Sir if u have time answer this question too..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828333/holoeverywhere-still-remains-as-a-puzzle